# Cancel my vote-to-reopen a question flagged with a wrong duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

I got 3000 reputation points today and with that, the new close and reopen privilege.

I just voted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790315/how-to-chek-for-any-of-a-variabels-values) for reopen for the first time but now I'm almost sure I did it wrong.

My intention was to cancel the wrong duplicate flag, and then apply a new correct one.

I also made a comment under the question:

> The duplicate is about finding in an array, but this snippet seems to be about a tuple (although it will certainly have a duplicate too).

But just after voting I realized it is weird to vote for reopening a question that would be closed as duplicate a minute later.

---

I suppose I should have flagged for a moderator instead?

And should I flag for a moderator *now* to cancel my vote?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  It takes 5 reopen votes, I doubt this will get the other 4.  If it does-  having a duplicate question reopened isn't the end of the world.  Just be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suppose I should have flagged for a moderator instead?

No. Do not bother moderators with opening/closing question issues. The community handles this.

> And should I flag for a moderator now to cancel my vote?

I don't think moderators are even able to cancel your vote like this and they would not want to even if they could. And just like above, don't bother moderators with stuff the community handles like reopening/closing questions.

Reopen votes expire after a certain amount of time if the question remains closed. Just let it expire or check back later if you want to see if the question somehow was reopened. Then close as a dup of the other if you want.