# How to cancel my vote to close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, voting

I voted to close a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416220/vs-error-message-while-scaffolding-identity) by mistake. But I can't cancel that operation. Since there're two vote-to-close before mine, the question is closed now. But now I feel I shouldn't vote to close that question. It has already included the basic error information. I'm so sorry to vote to close.

My question is : How can I cancel my vote-to-close operation?

I found a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296713/cancel-my-vote-to-reopen-a-question-flagged-with-a-wrong-duplicate) talking about whether it is possible to cancel "vote-to-reopen'. However, that answer was about canceling the vote-to-reopen instead of canceling the vote-to-close. And it was written several years ago.

I cast a vote to reopen it. If I can't cancel my vote, is there something else that I can do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't retract the close vote because it has already been closed.

If you think the question is on-topic and reopen-worthy, you can get other users to vote to reopen, or perhaps just wait for the reopen review to complete first: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/24904212